# Make shell script service work with multiple files as input?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, automator

I have the following shell script (/bin/bash) saved as a service.

```
for f in "$@"
    do  ln -s "$@" "$@_deleteLinkExtAfterMoving.link"
done
```

The services receives files or folders as input, passed as arguments. It makes a symbolic link for a selected file/folder. However, the script fails if I select more than one file. How can I make this work with multiple files/folders selected so that I can make several symlinks at once, either on one of the local drive partitions, or a mounted USB storage drive?

On macOS 10.12.6 Sierra, Automator version 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

As written you code calls `ln -s` as many times as you have arguments using the whole list of arguments each time. Perhaps you meant:

```
for f in "$@"
    do  ln -s "$f" "${f}_deleteLinkExtAfterMoving.link"
done
```

If you want to make several links in the same `ln -s` call, then the target should be a directory.

```bsh
ln -s /path1/to/file1 /path2/to/file2 /path/to/target/directory
```

In that case the links are created with the base names of the sources  (ie `/path/to/target/directory/file1` and `/path/to/target/directory/file2`). In your case something like:

```
ln -s "$@" "/path/to/directory/with/links/to/files/to/delete"
```

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, thx for the correction